# How to sort Thunderbird by message count?

Tags: email, thunderbird, sorting

I am trying to sort the messages in my inbox by the number of messages from / to email address.

After having sorted by `Sort by -> From` and `Grouped By Sort` and then displaying the `Total` column, I am unable to sort by the `Total` while keeping the sort grouping intact.

How can I sort the messages in my inbox by message count in Thunderbird?

[image: Thunderbird inbox state after having sorted]

Comment: @amiregelz, thanks for the screenshot. The count 1,4,3,93,42,29 is showing for me too. But how do I sort that to get 1,3,4,29,42,93?

Comment: I searched for a solution too, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is not possible to sort the count in Thunderbird, I used python mail module to sort. My code is below

```
import email,collections
mboxfile = 'C:/INBOX'
for em in mailbox.mbox(mboxfile):
    mailids.append(em['From'])
Counter(mailids)
```

This has given what I expected. This can be used for To,Cc,Bcc fields too.

Comment: Can this be installed as an Add-on?

Comment: It is python code, I dont is there any addons exists for sorting via count

Comment: 11 years later ... is there any way to accomplish this within Tbird?

Comment: There is this addon which is (supposedly) not compatible with Thunderbird anymore: 
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/sender-frequency/

There's also an addon to disable compatability checking (which might allow adding that other addon), but that addon is no longer compatible :)

Comment: This answer had broken code. I submitted an edit that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Rajasankar's answer - which seemed broken for me, here was a working version

```python
from collections import Counter
# tqdm is used to show a progress bar 
from tqdm import tqdm
import mailbox

mbox_filename = "your_filename"
mailids = []

mbox = mailbox.mbox(mbox_filename)
for em in tqdm(mbox, total=len(mbox)):
    mailids.append(em['From'])

Counter(mailids)
```